# can't print a variable in a table from json recordset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a Json recordset, that is working perfectly, however so far I can't sort out how to place a value of the json array into an specific cell of a table.

this is my function that looks for the form and start printing the values but only if there is an input component inside the table

```
function process_response(response) {
  var frm = document.getElementById("form-ajax");
  var i;
  console.dir(response);      // for debug
  for (i in response) {
    if (i in frm.elements) {
      frm.elements[i].value = response[i];
    }
  }
}
```

and this is table

```
form id="form-ajax" action="form-ajax.php"> 
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="name" name="ID" maxlength="12" size="12"></td>
      <th scope="row"><input type="submit" value="1" /></th>
      <td></td>
```

this is the place where I want to the resultset without the need of place a input

if I place something like this.

`<td><input type="text" name="1" /></td>`

then the javascript works and it reads whatever is in the json name with 1.
but if I do something like this.
`<td name="1"></td>`
then **nothing** prints out.

Whatever I do different than place an input type="text" then the Function doesn't work.

I need to populate the table with an specific order from the json .

Comment: Add your response as test case

Comment: You can only use an input because you are identifying the elements with form elements. Identify the elements with tr's and td's for example..

Answer (score 1):

TDs are not part of a form and do not have value or name attributes

You could do

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td[name]"); 
for (var i=0;i<tds.length;i++) {  
  tds[i].innerText=response[tds[i].getAttribute("name")]; 
}
```

assuming the name attribute matches the response key

You also likely do not want to have a submit button but a type="button"

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a way to print an specific value inside the table ...

```
    var s = document.getElementById("so");
    s.innerHTML =response['sort'];
```

this way I force td component with ID="SO" to print the value I passed over the json file.

```
  <td id="so"></td>
```